# The Stickelberger relation in Ireland&Rosen's Number Theory book

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, characters, cyclotomic-fields

Could anyone please take a look at the very last expression at the very bottom of Ireland&Rosen page 214? I am refering to their A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory, 2nd Edition. The authors claim that the decomposition form $P^{\gamma^\prime}$ follows from Lemma8 of the same page whereas by my own calculation I thought there would be an additional multiplier $f$, ie, $f$ times the existing $\gamma^\prime$ of the text.

I have been trying to figure this out since this week... I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Please keep your questions self-contained. A reference to a page of a book (without title and edition, all the more) will not attract anyone to answering the question.

Comment: @darijgrinberg My bad! Thanks for kindly reminding!!

Comment: I'm sure this can be turned into an ok question. Do remember that the people capable of helping you may have their copy of I&R in their office, or they only use a library copy, or theirs is a different edition from yours. So, be a good kid and type up the relevant passage here, please. IOW, what Darij Grinberg said :-)